# How to get billing information from Google Cloud billing api

Tags: java, spring-mvc, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I am trying to get billing information such as the total cost per month.

I am using this library version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-billing</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Is it possible to get the cost of usage of my project?

Thank you

Comment: When asking questions like yours, write code and once you have a programming question, post your code and the problem. To answer your question, the library you specified is for managing Google Cloud Billing Accounts and not for calculating project spend. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Read this link to understand where costs are stored and how to access the cost items. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/cost-table

Answer (score 0):

To calculate your projects total cost per month you would need to check the Console [Billing Report](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reports). You can download or [export the data](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-file).

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports#faqs